# Header and Footer in handout using pgfpages

Tags: beamer

I am trying to print out page number/total number of pages in the handout that I get from this code: This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=10mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First}
\begin{itemize}
\item check1
\item check 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am well aware that I can do it using `pDfpages` as pointed out in [Actual page number (and total number of pages) in the handout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82920/actual-page-number-and-total-number-of-pages-in-the-handout/82951#comment178491_82951) . However, the problem with using `pDfpages` is that it does not preserve the original document's bookmarks. I was wondering if this is possible to do using `pGfpages` or any other package?

Comment: I had to read this a few times to notice the difference between `pdfpages` and `pgfpages` (pGf vs pDf)! This comment may help someone else too...

Comment: Thank you! I also edited the question make it very clear

Comment: My only idea so far would be to use the `textpos` package and add some `textblock*` environments as part of the `border code` for the first logical page, and put the header/footer in those, but it would need a fair amount of work which I'm afraid I'm not able to do right now, but maybe this will be a starting point for someone to find a solution...

Comment: Related: [How can I put page numbers or headers inside my handouts (handoutWithNotes)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28302). Maybe some more inspiration is possible from this other answer by Andrew Stacey about [how to draw horizontal rules in specific locations on the physical page with `pgfpages`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78905).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the [`lastpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) package to get the total number of pages and the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package to place the text `<current page> of <total pages>`; I counted only physical (not logical) pages of the handout, but this can be easily changed if desired. I chose to place the text centered at the top, but this can also be easily changed:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=10mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\usepackage{background}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgPosition{current page.north}
\SetBgVshift{10pt}
\SetBgContents{}
\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
{\SetBgContents{\the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax\ of \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}/2\relax}}%
{\SetBgContents{}}%
\bg@material}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First}
\begin{itemize}
\item check1
\item check 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Text 4
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interested reader may also look at this post as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82920/actual-page-number-and-total-number-of-pages-in-the-handout#autocomment178573